# After download fire javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net application where I am trying to write out a csv.  Once the dialog has displayed or after makes no difference, i simply want to display some message stating all went well.  I am trying to fire some javascript to simply change a style of an element as well as some test to show that the download was successful.

The download works fine and this is how I am doing it but also believe this is what is causing my issue:

```
       Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=myFile.csv");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "text/csv";

        FileInfo fileToDownload = new FileInfo(filename);

        Response.WriteFile(filename);
        Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        Response.End();
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "s_DisplayLongRunningQueryComplete", "DisplayLongRunningQueryComplete();", true);
```

If i move the last line where I am registering the startup script to its own button lets say I don't have any issues and it works just fine.  I have tried moving this to before the above fires too with no luck.

Anyone have any ideas how to make this work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems in this:

1-  You are downloading a file, and in your response you are trying to inject javascript code to execute along with file buffer. `System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` adds HTML Script tag to the response with the javascript you are trying to execute.

2- `Response.End()` is another problem. Assuming that your response is not for file download (for example), once you call this function, nothing else would get processed, so any web resources would not get called.

**How to resolve:**

You really have to restructure your code to resolve this.  Maybe try the following:

- change your code to download the file and not call the script.
- call the download from the client side via jQuery ajax.
- on success call you javascript code after the download.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I added response.end as it seemed if i did not have it when i would return the results I would get the page markup in addition to my results.  I like the idea of calling it client side but my server side methods are not static. Is there a way to call a non static method via jquery?

Comment: You can create an ASMX or WCF service that handles the file download.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send anything after **Response.End** is called. Basically, it stops execution of the page, and Thread is aborted.

If you want to display a message after downloading a file, you can use [jQuery File Download Plugin for Ajax](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/).

You can test the demo application [Here](http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/).

[Here](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload/tree/master/src) is the sample application.

[image]